# Cannot retrieve native file ffmpeg-amd64.exe

Tags: java, audio, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to convert video to audio . That is why , I am using the following code :

```
File source = new File("E:\\Shunno - Khachar Bhitor Ochin Pakhi.mp4");
        File target = new File("E:\\output.mp3");
        AudioAttributes audio = new AudioAttributes();
    audio.setCodec("libmp3lame");
    audio.setBitRate(new Integer(128000));
    audio.setChannels(new Integer(2));
    audio.setSamplingRate(new Integer(44100));
    EncodingAttributes attrs = new EncodingAttributes();
    attrs.setFormat("mp3");
    attrs.setAudioAttributes(audio);
    Encoder encoder = new Encoder();
    try
    {
        encoder.encode(source, target, attrs); 
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException | EncoderException e)
    { 
    }
```

But I am getting the following error  :

```
Sep 26, 2016 11:28:29 AM it.sauronsoftware.jave.DefaultFFMPEGLocator copyFile
SEVERE: Could not get native library for ffmpeg-amd64.exe
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot retrieve native file ffmpeg-amd64.exe
    at it.sauronsoftware.jave.DefaultFFMPEGLocator.copyFile(DefaultFFMPEGLocator.java:139)
    at it.sauronsoftware.jave.DefaultFFMPEGLocator.<init>(DefaultFFMPEGLocator.java:80)
    at it.sauronsoftware.jave.Encoder.<init>(Encoder.java:105)
    at Convert.main(Convert.java:29)
```

How can I solve this error ? Please help me .

Answer (score 2):

The error is very clear: ffmpeg cannot been found.

Since you hard coded some windows path [here is the windows binary](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) of ffmpeg. I suggest to download the x64 static version. Since that is just one file you need to care about.

If you need it for another platform check the [download site](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html).

Within the zip file in the subdirectory `bin` where the binary `ffmpeg.exe` is located. Now you need to renamed it to `ffmpeg-amd64.exe` since the library expects that name. Now you need to copy the file to a directory of your path variable e.g. `C:\windows\system32`. I suggest not to use that directory, but this is the simplest way. Better put it somewhere else and modify your path variable. There are dozens of explanations so just google them if you want how do achieve that.

Comment: Nice answer , though there is a problem , ffmpeg.exe depends on the other dlls , i want to pack it inside the ``jave-1.0.2 `` and replace the old default ffmpeg.exe that it contains ... how i can do that ? I mean make ffmpeg.exe not depend on the .dll files , i see the size of it is only 230 kb , how to pack all the .dll inside the ffmpeg.exe  .

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS Did you read this sentence: *"I suggest to download the x64 **static** version. Since that is just one file you need to care about."*. If you you static you have no problems with the dll files :-)

Comment: Oou my bad sorry , i checked everything except of static , much love :)))